# How can I make the speechRecognition and speechSynthesis API's work together?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am currently working on an experiment using the Web Speech API. The idea is to use speech recognition and synthesis to improve the user's experience with HTML forms. Keep in mind that the code below is just a concept and has many issues. However, it seems that the `speechRecognition` API and the `speechSynthesis` API do not work well together. My desired result is that when an input or button receives focus, the label will be read using `speechSynthesis` and then it will listen to the user's answer using `speechRecognition`. That seems to be working as expected.

The issue is, that after the `speechRecognition` has started for the first time the `speechSynthesis` get's much lower in volume and somethings just fail (does not read). I have added some logic to abort the recognition on focus loss but this does not seem to work. Has anyone ever ran into this issue? Am I doing something wrong? Any help is welcome.

EDIT: StackOverflow does not ask for the user's mic permissions, please use this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzt0nfp3/ for a working demo.

```js
const speechRecognition = !!window.SpeechRecognition || !!window.webkitSpeechRecognition ?
  new(window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition)() :
  false;

const speechSynthesis =
  "speechSynthesis" in window ? window.speechSynthesis : false;

if (!!speechRecognition && !!speechSynthesis) {
  let voice = null;
  speechRecognition.lang = "en-US";
  speechRecognition.continuous = false;
  speechRecognition.interimResults = false;

  const state = {
    speaking: false,
    listening: false
  };

  function loadVoice() {
    const voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

    let defaultVoice = null;
    let preferredVoice = null;

    voices.forEach(voice => {
      if (defaultVoice && preferredVoice) return;
      if (voice.default) defaultVoice = voice;
      if (voice.name.startsWith("Microsoft Jessa Online")) {
        preferredVoice = voice;
      }
    });

    voice = preferredVoice ? preferredVoice : defaultVoice;
  }

  loadVoice();
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = loadVoice;

  const abortRecognition = () => speechRecognition.abort();
  const startRecognition = () => speechRecognition.start();

  function speak(text) {
    if (speechSynthesis.speaking) speechSynthesis.cancel();

    if (text !== "") {
      const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
      utterThis.lang = "en-US";
      utterThis.voice = voice;
      utterThis.volume = 1;
      utterThis.pitch = 1;
      utterThis.rate = 1;

      utterThis.addEventListener("start", event => {
        state.speaking = true;
        console.log("Start Speaking.", state);
      });

      utterThis.addEventListener("error", event => {
        state.speaking = false;
        console.log("Error: " + event.error, state);
      });

      utterThis.addEventListener("end", event => {
        startRecognition();
        state.speaking = false;
        console.log("Stop Speaking.", state);
      });

      speechSynthesis.speak(utterThis);
    }
  }

  speechRecognition.addEventListener("start", event => {
    state.listening = true;
    console.log("Start Listening.", state);
  });

  speechRecognition.addEventListener("error", event => {
    state.listening = false;
    console.log("Error: " + event.error, state);
  });

  speechRecognition.addEventListener("end", event => {
    state.listening = false;
    console.log("Stop Listening.", state);
  });

  speechRecognition.addEventListener("result", event => {
    if (typeof event.results === "undefined") return;
    state.listening = false;

    const capitalize = s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
    const transcript = capitalize(event.results[0][0].transcript.trim());

    console.log("Transcript: " + transcript, state);

    if (transcript !== "") {
      const inputField = document.activeElement;
      inputField.value = transcript;
    }
  });

  document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("blur", () => abortRecognition());
    input.addEventListener("focus", e => {
      speak(e.target.parentElement.textContent.trim());
    });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll("textarea").forEach(textarea => {
    textarea.addEventListener("blur", () => abortRecognition());
    textarea.addEventListener("focus", e => {
      speak(e.target.parentElement.textContent.trim());
    });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("blur", () => abortRecognition());
    button.addEventListener("focus", e => {
      speak(e.target.textContent.trim());
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 5% 0;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 90%;
}

label {
  align-items: center;
  color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

input,
textarea {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  max-width: 350px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 blue;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

button {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 5rem;
  width: fit-content;
}

button:focus,
button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  color: blue;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Web Speech API</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label>My name is
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" />
      </label>
    <label>My business is
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company name" />
      </label>
    <label>You can email me at
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" />
      </label>
    <label>You can call me at
        <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" />
      </label>
    <label>My project is
        <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Description of my project, budget, time constraints..."></textarea>
      </label>
    <button type="submit">Get in touch</button>
  </form>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```